# VST plugin integration into ALSA?

Tags: audio, alsa

I have "headless" (e.g. no graphical front-end) VST plugin that I would like to embed into my ALSA setup to continuously filter my sound.
I remember that there used to be a `LADSPA` plugin which itself embedded/used VST plugins, but I can't seem to find it anymore.

Is there a way to use a VST plugin directly with ALSA? `jackd` is not much of an option here as it hangs too often on the target (Raspberry) when in real-time mode.